# Why am I getting the same value for the accuracy and recall when using spark's mllib's MulticlassClassificationEvaluator?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

So, I am having a play around with some tree based algorithms from Spark's mllib. The code I have is here;

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import (RandomForestClassifier, GBTClassifier, DecisionTreeClassifier)
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.logConf', 'true').set("spark.ui.port", "4060")

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).appName("Gradient Boosted Tree").getOrCreate()

data = spark.read.parquet('/mydata/location)

def yt_func(x):
    if x <= 10:
        yt = 0
    else:
        yt = 1
    return yt

yt_udf = udf(yt_func, IntegerType())

data = data.withColumn('yt_1',yt_udf(data['count']))

datasub = data.select('feature1', 'feature2',
                      'feature3', 'feature4',
                      'feature5', 'feature6',
                      'feature7', 'feature8',
                      'feature9', 'feature10',
                      'feature11','feature12',
                      'feature13')

datasub = datasub.na.fill(0)

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ['feature1', 'feature2',
                      'feature3', 'feature4',
                      'feature5', 'feature6',
                      'feature7', 'feature8',
                      'feature9', 'feature10',
                      'feature11','feature12',
                      'feature13'], outputCol = 'features')

output = assembler.transform(datasub)

finaldata = output.select('features','yt_1')

train_data,test_data = finaldata.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

finaldata.show(20)

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='yt_1')
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='yt_1', numTrees=70)
gbt = GBTClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='yt_1')

dtc_model = dtc.fit(train_data)
rfc_model = rfc.fit(train_data)
gbt_model = gbt.fit(train_data)

dtc_preds = dtc_model.transform(test_data)
rfc_preds = rfc_model.transform(test_data)
gbt_preds = gbt_model.transform(test_data)

dtc_preds.show()
rfc_preds.show()
gbt_preds.show()

accuracy_eval = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName = 'accuracy', labelCol='yt_1')
recall_eval = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName = 'weightedRecall', labelCol='yt_1')

print 'dtc accuracy:', accuracy_eval.evaluate(dtc_preds)
print 'dtc recall', recall_eval.evaluate(dtc_preds)

print 'rfc accuracy:', accuracy_eval.evaluate(rfc_preds)
print 'rfc recall', recall_eval.evaluate(rfc_preds)

print 'gbt accuracy:', accuracy_eval.evaluate(gbt_preds)
print 'gbt recall', recall_eval.evaluate(gbt_preds)
```

When I run this I get the following;

```
dtc accuracy: 0.98596755767033761
dtc recall: 0.98596755767033761

rfc accuracy: 0.98551077243825225
rfc recall: 0.98551077243825225

gbt accuracy: 0.98624595624862965
gbt recall: 0.98624595624862965
```

What is confusing me here is why I am getting the same values for the accuracy and the recall.... they are EXACTLY the same. Surely this isn't correct....??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to this question can be found where I posted the same question on the Data Science Stack Exchange

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40160/why-am-i-getting-the-same-value-for-the-accuracy-and-recall-when-using-sparks-m